# Use Jenkins to read email, download attachment, and run a script

Tags: email, jenkins, attachment

I'm trying to configure the poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin to do this but having trouble setting it up. Unsure if downloading an attachment is possible with this plugin.

Here's what I'm trying to do

1. Jenkins reads email
2. If subject = "My Subject", download its attachment to /opt/file.csv
3. Run /opt/script.py

I'd like to do this in Jenkins but I may settle to write a script that can do all of the above steps instead and then have Jenkins just monitor it somehow.

Any suggestions?

Edit: There is an open feature request for this jenkins plugin for exactly this functionality.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading attachments is now available since [version 1.022](https://github.com/jenkinsci/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin/milestone/1?closed=1).